# Is GL_ARB_compatibility valid in a core proflie?

Tags: opengl

I've got a program that uses OpenGL for rendering. In doing so, it depends on having a core profile, but even if there is no core profile available, I always want to create an OpenGL context if only to be able to query the driver vendor and version when reporting the error that no suitable profile is available. For that reason, even if there is no core profile available, I always use *some* available profile to just attempt to initialize, and check during initialization that the profile fits my prerequisites, which specifically are that the OpenGL version is at least 3.0, and that `GL_ARB_compatibility` is absent.

However, I'm getting error reports from users whose drivers appear to violate those assumptions. Here's an example:

- GL_VENCOR: `ATI Technologies Inc.`
- GL_VERSION: `4.2.11411 Core Profile Context`
- GL_RENDERER: `AMD Radeon HD 7610M`
- GL_EXTENSIONS: [...] `GL_ARB_compatibility` [...]

As can be seen, `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` says it is a "Core Profile Context", but `GL_EXTENSIONS` contains `GL_ARB_compatibility`.

How should I interpret this? Is this a valid configuration and, if so, what does it mean for functionality that differs between core and compatibility profiles? Or should it be considered a driver bug? Is there a better way to check whether a given OpenGL context is core or compatibility?

Comment: There's no concept of profiles in OpenGL 3.1, even less so in 3.0. So if you run your software on a maximal implementation of OpenGL 3.1 (not capable of 3.2 or higher), you'll get `GL_ARB_compatibility` regardless.

Comment: @Ruslan: Right you are, of course. I guess I'm already not supporting 3.0/3.1 without even having realized it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a core profile by *asking* for it when you create the context. If you ask for a core profile, either you get a core profile or context creation *fails*.

There's nothing to interpret: if you asked for a core profile, and you created a context, you got a core profile. You don't need to ask if a profile is core, because you should already know, since you asked to make one.

If you asked for a core profile, then you shouldn't care whether "GL_ARB_compatibility" is available or not; you shouldn't even be looking at it, and you definitely should not be querying functions based on it.

But if you really want to check if a context is core or compatibility, you can call `glGetIntegerv(GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK`. It will return a bitmask that contains either `GL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT` or `GL_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT`.

Comment: In order to use that logic, I'd have to create additional data structures to carry along into initialization how the context was created. I *could* of course do that, but if I can just query the context (a stage that I'm doing anyway), that would clearly be simpler. I mean, if there is no better way available, I'll of course do that, but that's why I'm asking.

Comment: As for `GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK`, correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't it require OpenGL 3.3 or thereabouts? Part of the issue here is that I want to reliably be able to query these characteristics even in contexts like Microsoft's default OpenGL 1.1 software context that you get if no OpenGL driver is installed, while also not requiring above 3.0.

Comment: @Dolda2000: "*Part of the issue here is that I want to reliably be able to query these characteristics even in contexts like Microsoft's default OpenGL 1.1 software context*" Those characteristics *do not exist* in old OpenGL versions, so querying them makes no sense.

Comment: While true, the things I am currently querying (`GL_MAJOR_VERSION`, `GL_EXTENSIONS`, &c) do exist, which allows me to query, in a somewhat version-independent way, whether I'm on a matching context.

Comment: Either way, given everything, it seems asking for a core profile first and tracking whether the context came from that is the sensible option, so I'll mark this as the solution.

Comment: Though that being said, I'm still interested in what it even means for a "Core Profile" to advertise `GL_ARB_compatibility`, and whether it is to be considered a bug.

Answer (score 1):

> As can be seen, `glGetString(GL_VERSION`) says it is a "Core Profile Context", but `GL_EXTENSIONS` contains `GL_ARB_compatibility`.
> How should I interpret this?

Let me quote Appendix E.1 of the [OpenGL 3.2 core profile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec32.core.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> OpenGL 3.2 is the first version of OpenGL to define multiple profiles.
> The core profile builds on OpenGL 3.1 by adding features described in
> section H.1. **The compatibility profile builds on the combination of
> OpenGL 3.1 with the special `GL_ARB_compatibility` extension defined
> together with OpenGL 3.1**, adding the same new features and in some
> cases extending their definition to interact with existing features of
> OpenGL 3.1 only found in `GL_ARB_compatibility`.
>
> **It is not possible to
> implement both core and compatibility profiles in a single GL context,
> since the core profile mandates functional restrictions not present in
> the compatibility profile.** [...]

So, compatibility profile is explicitly defined in terms of relying on `GL_ARB_compatibility`, and I'd argue that an implementation advertising that extension in a core profile would be in violation of that section of the spec.